# how to display data from 2 in 2 loop php

Tags: php, for-loop, modulus

I have a table in my database with similar data, but others with more data.

What I want is to echo  the data through the loop. my problem is that I want to get data from 2 to 2.
 My code to display data normally is

```
<?php $count = $helper->count('testimony');?>
  <div class="owl-4">
    <?php for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) : ?>
      <div class="item">
      <?php echo '<h3>'.$helper->get('authorname', $i).'</h3>';
            echo '<p>'.$helper->get('testimony', $i).'</p>' ;?>
      </div>
    <?php endfor; ?>
  </div>
```

This returns

```
<div class="owl-4">
    <div class="item">
        <h3>Author 1</h3>
        <p>Testimony 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h3>Author 2</h3>
        <p>Testimony 2</p>
    </div>
    ................
</div>
```

How do I turn gives me this

```
<div class="owl-4">
    <div class="item">
        <h3>Author 1</h3>
        <p>Testimony 1</p>

        <h3>Author 2</h3>
        <p>Testimony 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h3>Author 3</h3>
        <p>Testimony 3</p>

        <h3>Author 4</h3>
        <p>Testimony 4</p>
    </div>
    ................
</div>
```

THANKS

Comment: @AlexAndrei `$i+=2` or `$i = $i + 2` as the increment, your version wouldn't increment $i and would create an infinite loop

Comment: @JonStory, yep, thanks, I removed the evidence of stupidity :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just increase the counter by 2 instead of 1 each time.

```
<?php $count = $helper->count('testimony');?>
<div class="owl-4">
    <?php for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i += 2) : ?>
        <div class="item">
        <?php 
            echo '<h3>'.$helper->get('authorname', $i).'</h3>';
            echo '<p>'.$helper->get('testimony', $i).'</p>' ;

            echo '<h3>'.$helper->get('authorname', $i + 1).'</h3>';
            echo '<p>'.$helper->get('testimony', $i + 1).'</p>' ;
        ?>
        </div>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can display `<div class="item">`and `</div>` each two iterations, for example checking if `$i` is an even number:

```
<?php $count = $helper->count('testimony');?>
<div class="owl-4">
<?php for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) : ?>
  <?php if ($i%2==0): ?>
     <div class="item">
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php echo '<h3>'.$helper->get('authorname', $i).'</h3>';
        echo '<p>'.$helper->get('testimony', $i).'</p>' ;?>
  <?php if ($i%2==0): ?>
     </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: Although this does work, it seems pointless (and slightly confusing because you're not doing what the user would automatically expect) when you can just increment by 2 in the loop? eg `for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i += 2)`

Comment: @JonStory if you increment by 2 you have to repeat the echo just like in the other answer

Comment: True, but it's more logical IMO. Like I said, it's not necessarily wrong, but the other solution is cleaner.